# Explanation for a parameter in ADTK package

Tags: python, time-series

I have a doubt with [LevelShiftAd](https://adtk.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/detectors.html#adtk.detector.LevelShiftAD.fit) in ADTK package. Can someone explain the parameter c (Factor used to determine the bound of normal range based on historical interquartile range) please?

Answer (score 1):

It is used in combination with the range of historical interquartile values to determine if a value is anomalous or normal. The range of normal values is defined as follows: $[Q_1 - c * IQR, Q_3 + c * IQR]$. See also [the example in the demo section](https://arundo-adtk.readthedocs-hosted.com/en/stable/notebooks/demo.html#InterQuartileRangeAD) of the documentation for `InterQuartileRangeAD`. Based on [the source code](https://adtk.readthedocs.io/en/stable/_modules/adtk/detector/_detector_1d.html#LevelShiftAD), this logic seems to be applied to the difference of the medians in the two time windows used.